# Why wont this run as a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR /R "C:\folder_LOCATION" %f IN (*.png) DO REN "%f" *.jpg
```

Runs fine in the command line however, whenever I drop it into a batch file - nothing!

I think its exiting before it even executes

Comment: Is there anything else in your batch file? How are you calling the batch file?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for.html; count the number of percent signs in the examples

Comment: Looks like a powershell command(?) to me. You'll need to put it in a powershell script file, then execute the script file in the batch file. Another tip is that you can add the keyword `pause` after that inside the batch file to see what the error message is saying.

Comment: @Cameron - no, those are DOS commands.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Fair enough. Never done that using DOS before. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OMG I am such a noob to batch files - hand head in shame and shuffle off - cheers Magoo!

Answer (score 1):

As ever, a batch file requires that the `%` in the metavariable (`%f` in our case) is doubled throughout. One from the prompt, two within a batch file.